# Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I've been reading up on this error but am now confused. I'm trying to run my java test file from the win7 cmd line but am getting that dreaded error cannot find class in classpath.

The script runs fine as a testNG file inside the Eclipse IDE but not from the cmd line.

My classpath dump:

```
C:\lib\selenium-java-2.37.0.jar;
C:\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar;
C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\bin;
C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\src\com\proteinbar\staging;
C:\TestNG;
```

My cmd line test string:

```
java -cp C:\lib\*;C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\bin org.testng.TestNG DeleteBillingAddress.xml
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Which class is missing?

Comment: `java -cp` ignores/overrides your environment's `CLASSPATH`. You need to use one or the other.

Comment: This class is missing: com.proteinbar.staging.DeleteBillingAddress

Comment: Which would make perfect sense, since that's not on the supplied classpath.

Comment: @Brian - I added C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\src\com\proteinbar\staging to the classpath but no success. Did I add that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't appear that the testng jars are on your classpath.  I'm guessing they live under c:/testng so you'll want to add something to your -cp reflecting that.

Comment: The TestNG jars are located in c:\TestNG;

Comment: right.  and c:\testng is, in no form, on your classpath.  you have to include those jars on your classpath.  and they're not in c:\lib either, apparently, so that * entry won't grab them either.

Comment: I added the testNG jar files to the classpath as c:\TestNG\\*.jar but I get the same results :-(

Comment: My classpath now looks like this:C:\lib\selenium-java-2.37.0.jar;
C:\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar;
C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\bin;
C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\src\com\proteinbar\staging;
C:\TestNG\*.jar;
C:\lib\*;
C:\Users\rfresh\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20130914_0724\lib

Comment: I finally got it to work from the cmd line with this: java -cp C:\lib\*;C:\EclipseIDE\ProteinBar\bin org.testng.TestNG DeleteBillingAddress.xml -- I did make some classpath edits. My .java files are not in the \bin folder so I really don't know why this works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the jars individually, e.g., 
java -cp C:\lib\selenium-java-2.37.0.jar;C:\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar;...

Comment: Not for the last 7 years you haven't. 1.6+ supports the `*` wildcard in the classpath for jar files. `C:\lib\*` picks up both of those jars.

Comment: I added c:\lib\* to the classpath but still the same error: Cannot find class in classpath: com.proteinbar.staging.AddNewAddress. Below is my .xml file that I'm trying to run:

Comment: <suitename="LoginTestSuite">
<testname="TestCase.javaFunctionalDescription:InitialLoginTests"preserve-order="true">
<classes>
<classname="com.proteinbar.staging.AddNewAddress"></class>
<methods>
<includename="AddNewAddress"/>
</methods>
</classes>
</test>

<testname="TestCase.javaFunctionalDescription:Test5LoginTests"preserve-order="true">
<classes>
<classname="com.proteinbar.staging.DeleteBillingAddress"></class>
<methods>
<includename="DeleteBillingAddress"/>
</methods>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>